# C# Client-Server Sockets not connecting

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server

I typed in a C# client/server lesson from the following video tutorial,...

[C# Socket Programming - Multiple Clients](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xgLRe7QV6QI)

I complied the program using Visual Studio 2017.

The program complied without error and it works in a SINGLE computer.  That is to say that if I run both the client and the server on the same computer they connect just fine.  So everything appears to be working.

However, when I try to put the client and server on different computers on my home network they won't connect.   When asked by the security firewall I allow them both to have full access.

I'm not understanding why they won't work when placed on different computers on the same home network connected via WiFi.  The computers share files with no problems.

Also, under the video lesson on YouTube is a link to the files already typed out.  I even copy and pasted those into Visual Studio and compiled them.  But I get precisely the same result.  They compile and run just fine on a single machine, but I can't get them to connect on different machines.

Any ideas?

I have no use for a computer that can only connect to itself.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's a link to the hard-copy client code:

[Multi Client](https://github.com/AbleOpus/NetworkingSamples/tree/master/MultiClient)

And here's a link to the hard-copy server code:

[Multi Server](https://github.com/AbleOpus/NetworkingSamples/tree/master/MultiServer)

It's a very short program.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  Do I need to add something more to get it to actually recognize a computer other than itself?

Code for the Client:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace MultiClient
{
class Program
{
    private static readonly Socket ClientSocket = new Socket
        (AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    private const int PORT = 100;

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.Title = "Client";
        ConnectToServer();
        RequestLoop();
        Exit();
    }

    private static void ConnectToServer()
    {
        int attempts = 0;

        while (!ClientSocket.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                attempts++;
                Console.WriteLine("Connection attempt " + attempts);
                // Change IPAddress.Loopback to a remote IP to connect to a remote host.
                ClientSocket.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, PORT);
            }
            catch (SocketException) 
            {
                Console.Clear();
            }
        }

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Connected");
    }

    private static void RequestLoop()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@"<Type ""exit"" to properly disconnect client>");

        while (true)
        {
            SendRequest();
            ReceiveResponse();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Close socket and exit program.
    /// </summary>
    private static void Exit()
    {
        SendString("exit"); // Tell the server we are exiting
        ClientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        ClientSocket.Close();
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    private static void SendRequest()
    {
        Console.Write("Send a request: ");
        string request = Console.ReadLine();
        SendString(request);

        if (request.ToLower() == "exit")
        {
            Exit();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sends a string to the server with ASCII encoding.
    /// </summary>
    private static void SendString(string text)
    {
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
        ClientSocket.Send(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
    }

    private static void ReceiveResponse()
    {
        var buffer = new byte[2048];
        int received = ClientSocket.Receive(buffer, SocketFlags.None);
        if (received == 0) return;
        var data = new byte[received];
        Array.Copy(buffer, data, received);
        string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
}
```

Code for the Server:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace MultiServer
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        private static readonly List<Socket> clientSockets = new List<Socket>();
        private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
        private const int PORT = 100;
        private static readonly byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

        static void Main()
        {
            Console.Title = "Server";
            SetupServer();
            Console.ReadLine(); // When we press enter close everything
            CloseAllSockets();
        }

        private static void SetupServer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting up server...");
            serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PORT));
            serverSocket.Listen(0);
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
            Console.WriteLine("Server setup complete");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Close all connected client (we do not need to shutdown the server socket as its connections
        /// are already closed with the clients).
        /// </summary>
        private static void CloseAllSockets()
        {
            foreach (Socket socket in clientSockets)
            {
                socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                socket.Close();
            }

            serverSocket.Close();
        }

        private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket;

            try
            {
                socket = serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException) // I cannot seem to avoid this (on exit when properly closing sockets)
            {
                return;
            }

           clientSockets.Add(socket);
           socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, socket);
           Console.WriteLine("Client connected, waiting for request...");
           serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
        }

        private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket current = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            int received;

            try
            {
                received = current.EndReceive(AR);
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Client forcefully disconnected");
                // Don't shutdown because the socket may be disposed and its disconnected anyway.
                current.Close(); 
                clientSockets.Remove(current);
                return;
            }

            byte[] recBuf = new byte[received];
            Array.Copy(buffer, recBuf, received);
            string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recBuf);
            Console.WriteLine("Received Text: " + text);

            if (text.ToLower() == "get time") // Client requested time
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Text is a get time request");
                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
                current.Send(data);
                Console.WriteLine("Time sent to client");
            }
            else if (text.ToLower() == "exit") // Client wants to exit gracefully
            {
                // Always Shutdown before closing
                current.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                current.Close();
                clientSockets.Remove(current);
                Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Text is an invalid request");
                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Invalid request");
                current.Send(data);
                Console.WriteLine("Warning Sent");
            }

            current.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, current);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** I think the code is probably just fine.  My problem is most likely a problem with permissions?  Or Firewall settings?  Or maybe I need to specify IP addresses?

Obviously this program doesn't report any errors.  It just won't connect between two laptops that are connected via WiFi on the same network.

It works just fine if the client and server are run on the same computer.  But that's pretty useless.

Comment: Please take the time to read [ask] and post a [mcve].

Comment: If you tried to connect from the two different machine on the same network , you need to specify the IP address(server machine) on the client Machine. Also please check your firewall .

eg : ClientSocket.Connect("specify the server IP", PORT);

Answer (score 0):

Ok, BEN SEBASTIAN answered my question.

All I had to do was specify the server IP in the Client software.

```
ClientSocket.Connect("specify the server IP", PORT);
```

I thought I had tried that yesterday and couldn't get it to work, but today it connected with no problem.   So that's all that was required.

Unfortunately the original video tutorial didn't elaborate on that point, or if he did I missed it.

In any case, this solved the problem.

Thanks Ben for taking the time to read and reply to my question.

Now I'll need to find a way to make sure my server notebook is guaranteed to always have the same IP address.  I'm not sure if it is being assigned one by the WiFi router, or if it's hard-coded into the notebook.  It's probably being dynamically assigned so I'll probably want to modify that to be sure that it's always the same.  Can't have a server with an undependable IP address.